# Free Member Inline Errors not working for freemember:update_profile

Tags: freemember, expresso

I am using EE 2.5.2 and Free Member 2.2.1

I am using the example code and error_handling isn't working for me.

What am I missing?

Comment: What happens when you remove the `error_handling` parameter?

Comment: I get the EE error which says: The form you submitted contained the following errors. The Current Password field is required. Return to Previous Page.

Comment: Can you add your template code to the question? Hard to diagnose without knowing what your code looks like (just cut it down to the minimum possible code needed to recreate the problem).

Comment: It's the same as your example code on Git Hub.

Answer (score 1):

You don't make any mention of how you're using FreeMember or how it isn't working for you so I'll take it on the basis that it's for a standard registration form where errors are not showing for required fields.

In this case you need to specify both the error handling and required parameters in the FreeMember tag like this along with any specific rules for each field like this:

```
{exp:freemember:register
    require="first_name|last_name"
    rules:first_name="required|min_length[5]"
    error_handling="inline"
}

    fields here...

{/exp:freemember:register}
```

Include all the fields you wish to be mandatory in the `require` parameter separated by a pipe character. In this case I'm specifying inline error handling (errors to appear in line with the form fields).

Then upon submission if those requirements and rules aren't met by the field values then the errors will be triggered.

Comment: I am using the free member:update_profile form to enable members to update their passwords.

I am using the default template code: https://github.com/expressodev/freemember/wiki/Update-Profile-Tag

The default code has current_password as required.
When submitting the form (leaving current_password blank) I get no inline errors.

Are there any extra steps I need to take?

- Adding additional member fields for example?